# what is the additivity of mutual information?

Tags: probability, entropy, information-theory, mutual-information

I've heard that if $x$ and $y$ are independent, then the following inequality holds $ I(z;x) + I(z;y) \le I(z;x,y)$

But if $x$ and $y$ are not independent, then how would such inequality change?

that is, what is then the relationship between $I(z;x)$,$I(z;y)$,and $I(z;x,y)$ ?